# Return a model field in django view set

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

I have a problem with my views,I'm trying to write a view to return my user membership if user has in site,but I get an error
membership model is:

```
    class Membership(models.Model):
    membership_type = models.CharField(
        choices=MEMBERSHIP_CHOICES,
        default='Free',
        max_length=30)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, default=0, decimal_places=3)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.membership_type
```

user membership is:

```
    class UserMembership(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='user_membership')
    membership = models.ForeignKey(Membership, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, null=True, related_name='membership',
                                   default='Free')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.email
```

view is:

```
    class MembershipView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = UserMembership
    serializer_class = UserMemberShipSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_membership_qs = UserMembership.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        if user_membership_qs:
            membership = user_membership_qs.membership
            return membership
```

I tried Return Response(membership) too,but didn't work,

Error is: object of type 'Membership' has no len()

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem answer
what should I do is:

```
    
    class MembershipView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = UserMembership
    serializer_class = UserMemberShipSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        user_membership_qs = UserMembership.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        if user_membership_qs:
            membership = user_membership_qs.membership
            return membership.membership.all()
```